# Aggregate a measure e.g revenue for the previous month but similar period as MTD

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

So i have MTD revenue done and displayed on my dashboard, The only caveat is that my MTD is not really month to date since my data source is not automatically updated. This is done manually and therefor most of the time the most recent data is T-2. My next requirement is to compare this Month to Max_date revenue to the previous month but for a similar period as Month to max_date. For example... Today is 19th Nov the revenue is $2000. I am trying to calculate October's revenue for the period 1st to 19th. Check out this script,

```
select sum (ld.revenue) as revenue 
from lifetime_data2 as ld
join 
dim_date dd
on ld.matchdate = dd.datenum
where  ld.date_started
between date_trunc('month', max(date_started) - INTERVAL '1 month')
and max(date_started) - INTERVAL '1 month'
```

Trying to find an alternate solution since i cannot use the max aggregate in the where clause

Comment: `date_started` is in which table?`dd` or `ld` You can use `subquery`

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy sorry about that date started is in ld

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select sum(ld.revenue) as revenue 
from lifetime_data2 ld join 
     dim_date dd
     on ld.matchdate = dd.datenum cross join
     (select max(date_started) as max_ds from lifetime_data2) m
where ld.date_started >= date_trunc('month', m.max_ds - INTERVAL '1 month') and
      ld.date_started < m.max_ds - INTERVAL '1 month';
```

This calculates the maximum in a subquery and then uses that for the filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subquery`

```
select sum (ld.revenue) as revenue 
from lifetime_data2 as ld
join 
dim_date dd
on ld.matchdate = dd.datenum
where  ld.date_started
between (select date_trunc('month', max(date_started) - INTERVAL '1 month') from lifetime_data2)
and (select max(date_started) - INTERVAL '1 month' from lifetime_data2)
```